# MAX31865 overvoltage/undervoltage fault caused by noisy environment

Tags: arduino, dc-dc-converter, noise, temperature, isolation

I have four [MAX31865](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31865.pdf) RTD temperature sensor ICs using 3-wire PT100 sensors in an electrically noisy environment.

I used an isolated DC-DC converter ([SPBW03F-03](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Mean%20Well%20PDF%27s/SPBW03,DPBW03_Series_Ds.pdf)) in the hope of isolating the measurement module to prevent interference and/or voltage potential between the battery supply and the RTD inputs.

I think I might have misunderstood how isolation works in reference to shielding and the MAX31865 over/under voltage protection fault. Each PT100 is connected as seen in this schematic (note: MAX31865 DVDD and VDD bypassed with 0.1 μF caps, not shown):

[image: MAX31865 Schematic]

Each PT100 sensor has its shield grounded just before the module, the module itself is in a plastic enclosure with no ground bonding. Reading the voltage between any of the PT100 lines and where the shields are grounded shows about 0.9 V of AC ripple. The MAX31865 specifies that any voltage greater than VDD or less than GND1 will trigger an over/under voltage fault.

Connecting the negative side of the battery to where the shields are grounded greatly reduces the number of faults. I am using the Adafruit MAX31865 library with a 10 ms delay between enabling bias and starting the measurement and then another 65 ms before reading the result.

Questions:

- Is my thought process wrong? Is there a better way to implement isolated PT100 sensor inputs using the MAX31865?
- Should I be tieing FORCE/RTDIN- and/or ISO_GND to the same ground as the shields via decoupling caps?
- Would it be better to bond the shields to the isolated ground (ISO_GND) from the DC-DC?

Comment: Maybe try some bulk capacitance on the power rails. With your grounding - where is the interference coming from and where will it find its way back to earth via your circuit?

Comment: I have about 10uF on capacitance between ISO_3V3 and ISO_GND. As far as grounding goes, I thought having the circuit isolated would allow it to "float" and not be affected by external voltages/interference. The only path to earth is for the shield of the sensor cables.

Comment: You can’t escape capacitance - whilst your circuit might float at DC, what happens with AC is where the problems begin. Have you ruled out piezo electric effects with cables and Capacitors?

Comment: I have not ruled out piezo effects. Looking at the datasheet closer, I can see that testing is done with the FORCE- disconnected from ground. I think that with my power supply and CANBus being isolated from the rest of the network I will be ok to ground one side of the PT100 at the same potential as the shield/earth. Does this seem reasonable? Any issues with paralleling one side of PT100 sensors. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the issue? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: @Ohbhatt I have not had a chance to get back to this device to test any theories, however, I believe that adding a capacitor between the negative and shield ground would greatly reduce the issue. Also, the isolated power supply could benefit from some filtering in the form of an LC filter or ferrite bead.